# Changing google chrome auto-suggestion options background

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I wanted to change the background of Google Chrome auto-suggestion options!
I have tried the below code sniped and I change everything regarding suggestion, but I can not change the background of the options.

```
/* Browser autofill options */
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:active,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:active,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
  transition: background-color 50000s ease-in-out 0s, color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

[image]

From the image I think this is bit clear that i want to change the background of the option for example here ["Mithun","Admin"].